# Python exception handling of logging itself

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, logging

While I use `logging` to record exceptions, it occurred to me the methods of the `logging` library itself can throw exceptions.

For example, if a "bad" path is set for the log file, like

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='/bad/path/foo.log')
```

a `FileNotFoundError` will be thrown.

Suppose my goal of handling these `logging` exceptions is to keep the program running (and not exit, which the program would otherwise do). The first thing that comes to mind is

```
try:
    logging.basicConfig(filename='/bad/path/foo.log')
except Exception:
    pass
```

But this is considered by [some to be an antipattern](https://realpython.com/the-most-diabolical-python-antipattern/). It's also quite ugly to wrap every `logging.error` with `try` and `except` blocks.

What's a good pattern to handle exceptions thrown by logging methods like `basicConfig()`, and possibly by `debug()`, `error()`, etc.?

Comment: The example you have given is one about a wrongly configured logging module. Why not configure it properly?

Comment: @rdas Just like runtime bugs, getting configurations right is not always as trivial as this example. This becomes more challenging if there are multiple deployment environments (e.g. staging, production, colos, Docker, AWS, etc.). Was this your line of questioning, or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: Configurations issues should be fixed with proper configuration - not code. IMO.

Comment: If there's a configuration issue, e.g. I've made a mistake, I want to know about it, not have it silently ignored by the application.

Comment: @rdas It sounds like your comment is about whether or not infrastructure as code is a good practice or not - am I right?

Comment: @TomCarrick Absolutely - agreed. However, we don't want every little thing to break production code or even block pipelines...that's one of the main reasons we have exception handling and different levels of loggers in the first place. Or did I miss your point?

Comment: No I think you missed my point entirely. If you think that your logger is "every little thing" then yeah you can wrap your logger in an object & use that to handle the exceptions thrown. Personally I wouldn't do that. Just configure your logger properly. If this same issue comes up in some other place (instead of the logger) - reevaluate & take it on a case-by-case-basis

Comment: @rdas Thanks for clarifying this. Although I don't agree 100%, I do think there are merits to your approach.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you re-initialise your logger mid-way through your code, why not just check whether the file exists during logger initialisation:

```
import os

if os.path.isfile(filename):

    # Initialise the logger
```

This should work normally, unless of course some part of the later code will attemp to delete the file, but I hope that it's not the case.

Comment: This idea could be made to work for that particular error I think - the next step would be to think about what to do if the file doesn't exist. Should some other logger be configured, so the logging methods sprinkled throughout the codebase have an expected behavior?

Comment: Also, is it not possible for other Exceptions to be thrown by `logging` as well?

Comment: @flow2k, I guess you need to check out doc for that. It's quite possible there will be quite a few possible exceptions thrown by logging module. You can also use `assert` in the beginning instead of `if` clause. That way if the file doesn't exist the program will throw `AssertionError` at the very start and not waste time running through other code.